# Message passing in Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, message-passing

I am quite confused about the what are counted as chrome extension view, which directly linked to what function I can use for passing messages between different components.

Let me just describe what I am trying to do first;

My background.html creates Desktop Notifications based on some events received from a node.js server through socket.io.

When the user clicks on the notification, I want to create a new tab pointing to a html within my extension (/src/view/token.html), and then send some data from the background.js (where my socket.io codes are) to the new tab. And I want to do this through message passing.

So, basically, i am doing

```
 var notification = webkitNotifications.createNotification(image, title, content);
 notification.onclick(function(e){

    chrome.tabs.create({url: "/src/view/tokens.html"}, function(tab){
        //just to make sure the tab is activated..
        chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId){
            if(tabId == tab.id) {
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage({data: whatever_data}, tabId); 
            }
        });
    });

 });
```

Now my problem is in my tokens.js (loaded in tokens.html), I try to listen for the message using:

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, _, sendResponse) {
console.log(msg);
});
```

but I am getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onMessage' of undefined:, so I assume that I don't have access to chrome.extension in the tokens.html???

I tried this with popup page (browser action popup) and option page, and they all worked just fine. So, I guess the view I created is just not a chrome extension page?

Now I am confused... 
1) What are considered as chrome extension pages that have access to the chrome.* API
2) How should I implement what I want to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Problems in your code

- [chrome.tabs.sendMessage()](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-sendMessage) wrong Invocation pattern
- As complete code is not shared, i assume permissions are given to all pages, because manifest don't [generate warnings](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permission_warnings.html) for some set of values.
- **`notification.onclick(function`** creates  `Uncaught TypeError: Property 'onclick' of object #<Notification> is not a function` error

**Chrome.tabs.sendMessage**

Invocation form of [chrome.tabs.sendMessage](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-sendMessage)({data: whatever_data}, tabId); should be [chrome.tabs.sendMessage](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-sendMessage)(tabId,{"data": "whatever_data"});  ***(Tab id followed by message).***

**notification.onclick(function**

Use `notification.onclick = (function(` assign handler to onclick property ***(because it is not a function)***

After fixing above problems i got your script running.

#### manifest.json

Registered background scripts and given all permissions needed.

```
{
    "name": "Message Passing",
    "description": "This is used as a message passing",
    "version": "1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ]
    },
    "permissions": [
        "notifications",
        "tabs"
    ]
}
```

#### background.js

Modified code to eliminate errors

```
//Created Notification
var notification = webkitNotifications.createNotification("icon.jpg", "title", "content");
//Added onclick property
notification.onclick = (function (e) {
    //Created new tab
    chrome.tabs.create({
        url: "/src/view/notification.html"
    }, function (tab) {
        //just to make sure the tab is activated..
        chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId) {
            if (tabId == tab.id) {
                //Send Mesage
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {
                    "data": "whatever_data"
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
notification.show();
```

#### notification.html

Ensure there is no `inline script` or `<script>` tag to comply with [CSP](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html).

```
<html>

    <head>
        <script src="notification.js">

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>This is a notification</p>
    </body>

</html>
```

#### notification.js

Used your script with no changes!

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, _, sendResponse) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(msg));
});
```

## Output

You can see message(s) being received in your new `tab`.

[image]

## References

- [CSP](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html)
- [Desktop Notifications](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications.html)
- [chrome.tabs.sendMesage](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-sendMessage)
- [chrome.extension.onMesage](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html#event-onMessage)

Comment: Thanks! Sorry about the error in the chrome.tabs.create... in my code it was tabId first, than the data... when I type in here... I wasn't looking...I will give it a try, and report back...

Comment: Yours works just fine... but i still can't understand why my previous one doesn't work... the notification.onclick was a typo as well... in my original code, it was notification.onclick = function(e)... the only difference is I am on a windows machine today... i was testing on a Mac... but i don't think that's the issue .............. weird......

Comment: Another thing is, on the Mac machine, if i do console.log(chrome). I only see chrome.app but not chrome.extension... weird...

Comment: @h0cked: When i do console.log(chrome) in windows i only see `chrome.app` because `chrome.extension` is limited to `chrome-extension://` protocol